# Consider the sequence $x_n = (7 + (-1)^n/n, -5) \in\mathbb{R^2}$. What are the sets of limit points in different topologies?

Tags: general-topology, limits

Consider the sequence $x_n = (7 + (-1)^n/n, -5) \in\mathbb{R^2}$.

i). Write down the set of limits in the standard topology

ii). Prove that the sequence has no limits in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the discrete topology

iii). Prove that every point in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is a limit point if $\mathbb{R^2}$ is given with the finite complement topology

i). My answer is (7, -5)

ii). For this one I think it involves the fact that the set {(7,-5)} is open in the discrete topology but there does not exist n st $x_n \in {(7, -5)}$

iii). Not sure how to approach this one.

Comment: First point is correct. For the second point: you proved that ${(7, -5)}$ isn't a limit point, but you have to prove it for every point in the plane (but of course the same argument applies for any point). As for the third: pick an open, non-empty set. Can you find an $m$ such that $x_n$ doesn't belong to its complement (which is finite) for every $n \geq m$?

Answer (score 0):

For (ii) probably the easiest approach is to prove that in the discrete topology, only stationary sequences converge.

(iii) is almost tautological if you know the definitions of limit point and finite complement topology. Pick any point in $\Bbb R^2$, any neighbourhood of it, and "prove" that this neighbourhood contains all but finitely many points of the sequence $x_n$.